# Downloading after trying out Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I am trying out Ubuntu. Can I be sure that when I click on "Download Ubuntu 16.4" it will download the 64 bit version which I need for my PC and not the 32 bit version?

Comment: If you are already trying out Ubuntu from a Live USB stack or DVD you don't need to download it again - simply click the "Install Ubuntu" icon in the dock, or restart, and choose "Install Ubuntu" - however, if you don't have Ubuntu yet, yes, it does offer the 64 bit version for download  by default, which will have amd64 in the name of the file you get when downloading, so you can check to be sure.

Comment: Hehe I'm writing down there just to see you already have answered it in a comment :)

Comment: Just look at the file name. In Ubuntu world amd64 means *for 64 bit CPU (both Intel and AMD)* , and x86, intel-x86 or x86-32 means *for 32 bit CPU  (both Intel and AMD, unless otherwise specified)*. ARM, armel or armhf means *for ARM CPU* - typically found in mobile devices.

Answer (score 6):

If you have already a live CD/USB you simply need to click on the installer in your doc to initiate the installation.

If not you can download the proper 64-bit image from the following link:

[direct dl - releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso)

[torrent - releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent?_ga=1.48071975.1868908608.1463824121)

As far as other downloads you can easily find it [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/) (server images, 32-bit images).

And for installation help and instructions you can follow [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/index.html).

Comment: Your link points to the torrent - are you sure that's what the OP wants ?

Comment: Oh, thank you will provide more links in a second :) you're right on that.